Window replacement advice
We need to replace most of our windows. It is a large home and there are 31 we'd like have done. We have received the following pricing so far Pella 92k, Durante 78k, Champion 89k, and Ecoview 41K.
We are going to get some more pricing but why would one be so much cheaper than the others? And why the hell are windows so much in the first place?

We do not do pricing/costs.  Why do you need to replace all the windows?

Without knowing the size and type of windows and installation rrquirements, it is impossible  to judge if the quoted costs are reasonable

Two very answerable questions here! One is cheaper because A) Lower quality material, B) Lower quality assurance allows more flaws to slip through, C) Built off-shore with cheaper labor, and/or D) The others extract more profit per unit. Why are windows so expensive? Because there are but so many options, and you end up having to pay whatever price the market will bare. These are economics questions that probably belong on [economics.se], not [diy.se].

I won’t comment on specific brands or prices, but in broad strokes, there are various quality levels available in everything, windows included. There are also different types of installs: insert windows are quicker, where full removal is slower. Warranty terms and duration will vary.
Some crews are concerned about quality finishing; others aren’t. Some make a mess and run; others clean up.
Long story short: try to compare apples to apples when looking at different bids. Read the fine print and see what is included or excluded. Only believe a salesperson if they’ve written it down.
